# SQL select with complicated conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm banging my head with some SQL query and pretty much the logic behind it.

Let's assume we have these tables:

**Table hotels**

```
+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
| 1  | Hotel A |
+----+---------+
```

**Table hotel_rooms**

```
+----+----------+-----------+
| id | hotel_id | room_type |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 1  | 1        | dbl       | <- can be used as A,B,C,D,E,F
| 2  | 1        | dbl       | <- can be used as B,C,D,E,F
| 3  | 1        | sng       | <- can be used as A
| 4  | 1        | trp       | <- can be used as D,E,F
+----+----------+-----------+
```

**Table hotel_room_usages**

```
+----+---------+-------+
| id | room_id | usage |
+----+---------+-------+
| 1  | 1       | B     |
| 2  | 1       | C     |
| 3  | 1       | A     |
| 4  | 1       | D     |
| 5  | 1       | E     |
| 6  | 1       | F     |
| 7  | 2       | B     |
| 8  | 2       | C     |
| 9  | 2       | D     |
| 10 | 2       | E     |
| 11 | 2       | F     |
| 12 | 3       | A     |
| 13 | 4       | D     |
| 14 | 4       | E     |
| 15 | 4       | F     |
+----+---------+-------+
```

If I search for 2 rooms with usage A **or** 3 rooms with usage D as separate queries the result should be Hotel A with the corresponding IDs of the rooms.

The problem is if I search for 2 rooms with usage A **and** 3 rooms with usage D at the same time it returns also the hotel A because it doesn't count that some rooms can be used as A and D.
The rooms should be unique /total of 5/. The current example should not return a result because there are total of 4 rooms in the hotel.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry the question is not about "why the query is not working".. is more about the logic.

Comment: Well, there's your way, and there's my way.

Comment: It would be way easier to simply do this on application level. Just select all available rooms and do the logic in the code.

Comment: @fancyPants I tried that, but is not so nice to work like that, because I need to select all hotels and search them one by one if there is a match. So I left it as a backup plan...

Comment: You can start with your `OR` approach and work from there. Then you don't have to select every hotel.

Comment: @AlexanderDimitrov can there be more than 2 **AND** conditions? I thought it was s simple as `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT room_id) FROM hotel_room_usages WHERE USAGE IN ('A', 'D') -- 4` but may be it isn't.

Comment: @SalmanA yes, the **AND** conditions can be **N**, so nobody knows :) It can be from 1 until N.

Comment: @AlexanderDimitrov I guess you mean there can be `0...n` usages ;)

Comment: @D.Schaller actually `1..n`. For 0 it will not perform the search at all..

Comment: @AlexanderDimitrov I refered to "how often can **AND** be used in a Query" ._.'

Comment: @D.Schaller sorry, my bad :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this help?

-- two rooms with usage a

```
select id from hotel_room_usages where usage = 'a'
```

-- three rooms with usage d

```
select id from hotel_room_usages where usage = 'd'
```

-- count of rooms with either

```
select count(distinct(room_id)) from hotel_room_usages where usage in ('a','d')
```

Comment: Actually thanks!

The query is something like this /ugly, but it works.../
`SELECT
 h.id,
 h.name,
 r.id
FROM
 hotels h
 JOIN hotel_rooms r ON r.hotel_id = h.id
HAVING
 (SELECT COUNT(r1.id) FROM hotel_rooms r1 JOIN hotel_room_accommodations a1 ON a1.room_id = r1.id WHERE a1.type = 'A') >= 6
AND
 (SELECT COUNT(r2.id) FROM hotel_rooms r2 JOIN hotel_room_accommodations a2 ON a2.room_id = r2.id WHERE a2.type = 'D') >= 13
AND
 (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT r3.id) FROM hotel_rooms r3 JOIN hotel_room_accommodations a3 ON a3.room_id = r3.id WHERE a3.type IN ('A', 'D')) >= 19`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> SELECT h.name AS hotel_name
> , q.*
> FROM
> (
>   SELECT r.hotel_id
>   , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ruA.room_id IS NOT NULL AND ruD.room_id IS NULL THEN ruA.room_id END) AS TotalRoomsOnlyA
>   , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ruD.room_id IS NOT NULL AND ruA.room_id IS NULL THEN ruD.room_id END) AS TotalRoomsOnlyD
>   , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ruA.room_id IS NOT NULL AND ruD.room_id IS NOT NULL THEN r.id END) AS TotalRoomsAandD
>   , COUNT(DISTINCT r.id) AS TotalRoomsAorD
>   FROM hotel_rooms AS r
>   LEFT JOIN hotel_room_usages AS ruA ON (ruA.room_id = r.id AND ruA.usage = 'A')
>   LEFT JOIN hotel_room_usages AS ruD ON (ruD.room_id = r.id AND ruD.usage = 'D')
>   WHERE (ruA.room_id IS NOT NULL OR ruD.room_id IS NOT NULL)
>   GROUP BY r.hotel_id
> ) q
> JOIN hotels AS h ON (h.id = q.hotel_id)
> CROSS JOIN (SELECT 2 AS a, 3 AS d) AS n
> WHERE TotalRoomsAorD >= (a+d)
>   AND (
>         ((TotalRoomsOnlyA + TotalRoomsAandD) >= a AND TotalRoomsOnlyD >= d) OR
>         (TotalRoomsOnlyA >= d AND (TotalRoomsOnlyD + TotalRoomsAandD) >= d) OR
>         ((TotalRoomsOnlyA + TotalRoomsAandD/2) >= a AND (TotalRoomsOnlyD + TotalRoomsAandD/2) >= d)
>       )
> ORDER BY h.name;
> ```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f5981b1f097f224e1834b0a40da51343)*